# LibGDX TiledMap doesn't render

Tags: java, render, libgdx, tile, tmx

I've started to move over from slick2d to Libgdx, and I'm trying to get .tmx files to work with libgdx. I followed the TileMap tutorials on the libgdx wiki but I can't seem to get my .tmx file to render. When I run it I get no errors, my other texture renders fine, but the .tmx is no where to be seen.

I used the libgdx-texturepacker-gui to create the pack file. If I had to guess what the problem was, I would guess it was the pack file, but I'm not sure what is wrong with it or how to fix it. I'm having the problem with the desktop version of the project (I haven't tried any other version of it), and all of the assets are in the android asset folder.

I uploaded the whole project with the assets in a zip file on [dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dgqvnfa26m6e9tq/ProjectFirefly.zip), because I thought it might be easier that way. Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a million different ways to get this to work and none of them worked. In the end I changed from using "TileAtlas" to "SimpleTileAtlas" and stopped messing around with pack files and now it works fine.

Comment: I was having the same problem, it was really anoying was like two days with it, Now using your suggestion, it's finally working. I think they need to mention it in the tutorials. Thanks